# Adding Google Analytics API Library to Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to run a simple python script on Google App Engine.  How do I install the Google Analytics API library?

Library: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/analytics/v3

Instructions: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring

I've tried everything and can't get this to run, even though it works on my pc.  What I have right now is: 
The python scripts in the root folder,
In the /lib folder I copied the folders that were installed from my PC (/googleapiclient and /google_api_python_client-1.4.0-py2.7.egg-info)
And I have appengine_config.py in /lib folder which contains:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
vendor.add('google-api-client')
```

app.yaml file:

```
application: psyched-cab-861
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: hello_analytics_api_v3.app
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
ImportError: No module named helloworld
```

New Log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 354, in __getattr__
    self._update_configs()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 290, in _update_configs
    self._registry.initialize()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 165, in initialize
    import_func(self._modname)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~just-terminus-94303/1.384249106864280829/appengine_config.py", line 5, in <module>
    vendor.add('google-api-python-client')
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/vendor/__init__.py", line 44, in add
    'No such virtualenv or site directory' % path)
ValueError: virtualenv: cannot access google-api-python-client: No such virtualenv or site directory
```

I tried editing the appengine_config.py file to

```
vendor.add('googleapiclient')  #The name of the file
```

I edit it in GAE, and click commit, it saves, but I get the same error as above with the vendor.add('google-api-python-client') error.  Why is the file not updating?

Comment: Are you using a virtual environement (created with `virtualenv`)?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Just using the default Google App Engine setup with Python and Flask

Comment: So, what's the name of your main python file?

Comment: hello_analytics_api_v3,py

Comment: No, that's just a misprint

Comment: I started fresh with a new project and now I am getting a different error message (added to op)

Comment: Have you tried placing the `appengine_config.py` file in the same directory as the `app.yaml` file, as suggested at the end of [Installing a third-party library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library)?

Answer (score 3):

As the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring) say: put the `appengine_config.py` in your **root** folder of the application (and not in the **/lib** folder).
By the way, the name of the library is `google-api-python-client` and not `google-api-client`.

Then you have to install `google-python-api-client` in your **/lib** folder:

```
$ pip install -t lib google-api-python-client
```

Comment: Thanks doru.  I'm still getting a 500 Server Error maybe its my app,yaml file?  I added it to the op.  My script is in hello_analytics_api_v3,py

Comment: Before you use `$ pip install -t lib google-api-python-client` you should navigate in your terminal to the root folder of the application and inside it run this command.

Comment: `$ pip install -t lib google-api-python-client` this command should be run inside of the root folder of the app.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's where I installed it, from the root folder and it installed into the /lib folder

Comment: Maybe if you paste into your question the error stack trace it gives some clues.

Comment: Added. Not sure where the helloworld is being called